# Connection between GoF Design Patterns and SOLID

Tags: oop, solid-principles, design-patterns

I am interested to know which GoF design pattern translates directly to a specific SOLID principle? Like for instance I think (in my opinion) the strategy pattern translates to the Dependency-Inversion Principle.

Unfortunately, I could not find any literature that examines their relationships. It would be nice to have to learn both more effectively with each others perspectives.

Comment: I'm quite satisfied by the answer in this old post, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/412914/patterns-to-implement-solid-principles

Comment: This webinar in InfoQ particularly discusses this topic, http://www.infoq.com/presentations/SOLID-Software-and-Design-Patterns-for-Mere-Mortals

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SOLID principles are applied in most of GoF's design patterns.

- S: Single responsability principle: the classes that are part of the
  DP, have only one responsability
- O: Open/Closed principle: it is easy
  to extend with new functionality, for example the strategy pattern
  allows you to implement an additional algorithm without having to
  change the other classes that contain other algorithms
- Liskov Substitution Principle: also applies to strategy for instance

Comment: I agree. It looks like one or more GoF design pattern will map to one or more SOLID principle. What I'd like is to have the complete mapping. I don't know for others but for me that will help me pick the correct design pattern based on the principle and the problem I have at hand.

Comment: There is no complete 'mapping'.  Design Patterns are solutions that can be used for a specific problem.   SOLID principles are principles that you should try to apply when designing software.

Answer (score 1):

GOF are patterns i.e. proven design solutions to recurring problems. SOLID are principles and are not tied to any specific problem domain hence true in any scenario

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your statement. But i believe that solution to be applied it will have to be guided by a principle. That makes me believe that there is a connection between both. Knowing that connection, like knowing the principle, will make it easier to select the correct design pattern given the problem at hand.

Answer (score 0):

There's a paper [A reference model for low level design](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/332397035_A_Reference_Model_for_Low-Level_Design), which lists the SOLID properties for some patterns in table 3:

- Facade: ISP, DIP
- Chain of Responsibility: SRP, OCP, LSP, ISP, DIP
- Decorator: SRP, OCP, LSP, ISP, DIP
- Factory: SRP, OCP, ISP, DIP
- Builder: SRP, ISP, DIP
- Adapter: SRP, ISP, DIP

I'd like to see such research for all patterns, but I'm not aware of similar papers.